# How to include fullcalendar locale on webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, webpack-2

I'm having an issue while importing the locale with fullcalendar. Here's what I'm trying:

```
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            moment: "moment",
            fullcalendar: ['fullcalendar/dist/locale/fi.js', "fullcalendar"],
            Select2: "Select2"
        }),
```

Any ideas how this should be done?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answering to my own question. In addition to

```
require("fullcalendar");
```

I had to do also

```
require("fullcalendar/dist/locale/fi.js");
```